# SQL to insert 200 Million records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to insert around 200M records into a table after doing a select from a fact table but a

> System.OutOfMemoryException

Following is my query :

```
Select 
    ProductID,
    SaleDate,
    Quantity 
from 
    dbo.Product 
where
    SaleDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2016-01-01';
```

The result of the above `SELECT` returns 200M records which is to be inserted in a table.

Can someone suggest an alternative?

Comment: Where is the `insert` ?

Comment: I haven't included the INSERT since the INSERT is performed using a custom plug-in. The plugin takes the result of the SELECT and inserts into the destination table.

Comment: What custom plug in?

Comment: Does the error come from your custom plug in or from SSMS? When you use your custom plug in what happens? You know that if you just put an insert in front of that you can avoid all of these problems.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned don't do the whole thing at once.  Step through it with smaller records.  Here is sample of someone else doing the same thing: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53831/large-insert-into-select-from-gradually-gets-slower

Answer (score 2):

you can do this in batchs, for example each time do one year or half year
The following is get one year data one time.

```
     DECLARE @StartYear INT =2012,@EndYear INT =2016,@iYear INT 
     SET @iYear=@StartYear+1
     WHILE @iYear<@EndYear
     BEGIN
         Select ProductID,SaleDate,Quantity from dbo.Product where SaleDate BETWEEN DATEADD(yy,@iYear-1900,0) AND DATEADD(yy,@iYear+1-1900,0); 
         SET @iYear+=1
     END
```

Answer (score 1):

The error `System.OutOfMemoryException` occurs because SSMS has insufficient memory to allocate for large results.

Try with a small set of data if possible by using `row_number()`.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ProductID,SaleDate,Quantity) AS rowid, 
    ProductID,SaleDate,Quantity 
    from dbo.Product where SaleDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2016-01-01'
    ) foo 
WHERE rowid BETWEEN 1 AND 500000;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have indexes on your target table drop them and create them after the insert.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SQL Server Integration Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx)

> Integration Services includes a rich set of built-in tasks and transformations; tools for constructing packages; and the Integration Services service for running and managing packages. You can use the graphical Integration Services tools to create solutions without writing a single line of code; or you can program the extensive Integration Services object model to create packages programmatically and code custom tasks and other package objects.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert a smaller record set. Start with selecting all of 2012. The error is throw because there's insufficient memory to allocate. Your select query is eating up all the memory, and that is why i recommend selecting less data.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I needed to insert about 20 million rows from one table to another. My solution was to splitting insertions into small pieces of SQL statements. Using the print command I generated thousands of queries and smoothly do my migration. The detailed way I do it look here https://yarkul.com/how-smoothly-insert-millions-of-rows-in-sql-server/